# entries in /proc/modules with respect to removable devices

Tags: kernel-modules

I was looking at my /proc/modules and to saw some wild entries in the file with regards to a usb stick, but is commented out !

Can anyone tell me, how can such an entry come into the /proc/modules?

Maybe from /etc/fstab? I had once hard coded this USB Stick in /etc/fstab, but also commented out the lines long ago. The computer in the meanwhile had gone multiple restarts.

```
#/dev/disk/by-id/usb-Verbatim_STORE_N_GO_070B35362BA99A92-0:0-part1 /mnt/usb-Verbatim_STORE_N_GO_070B35362BA99A92-0:0-part1 ntfs nosuid,    nodev,nofail,noauto 0 0
#/dev/disk/by-id/usb-Verbatim_STORE_N_GO_070B35362BA99A92-0:0-part1 /mnt/usb-Verbatim_STORE_N_GO_070B35362BA99A92-0:0-part1 ntfs nosuid,    nodev,nofail,noauto 0 0
#/dev/disk/by-id/usb-Verbatim_STORE_N_GO_070B35362BA99A92-0:0-part1 /mnt/usb-Verbatim_STORE_N_GO_070B35362BA99A92-0:0-part1 ntfs nosuid,    nodev,nofail,noauto 0 0
#/dev/disk/by-id/usb-Verbatim_STORE_N_GO_070B35362BA99A92-0:0-part1 /mnt/usb-Verbatim_STORE_N_GO_070B35362BA99A92-0:0-part1 ntfs nosuid,    nodev,nofail,noauto 0 0
```

The system is running fine, but I am just curious.

Comment: Are you sure you’re looking at `/proc/modules`?

Comment: 100 % sure, because I checked it in my vim history. It lists all the files that I opened today. Strangely, the Verbatim entries are gone now, because perhaps I modprobed a module. Unfotunately, I cannot even check the time stamp, because all the files in the proc folder has the same time stamp as the system clock.

Comment: All "contents" of the files in /proc is produced by code in the kernel (hence the time stamp), so either you discovered a bug, possibly udev writing where it shouldn't, or you did something else totally unrelated to `/proc/modules` which produced the output. Unless you can reproduce it, it will be hard to find out.